# Recursion in probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A biased coin shows head with a probability of $$\frac{3}{4}$$ and tails with a probability of $$\frac {1}{4}$$ Let $p_{n}$ denote the probability that no three or more heads appear consecutively in $n$ tosses of the coin.

If $$p_{n}=\alpha\, p_{n-1}+\beta\,p_{n-2}+\gamma\,p_{n-3}$$.

Find values of $\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$.

**My Attempt:**

I am able to understand the case when $n$th toss is a tail in which situation three or more consecutive heads should not have occurred in previous $(n-1)$ tosses with probability $p_{n-1}$. So, $\alpha$ equals $\frac{1}{4}$.

I am not able to relate with the other two cases.

Comment: Hint:  Any  "good" sequence of length at least $3$ must end in one of $T$, $TH$, or $THH$.

Comment: Your hint is a proper solution

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is a much better way but .......

I calculated $P_6, P_5, P_4, P_3$ and with $P_2 = P_1 = 1$.

Example: $P_3 = 3(\frac{3}{4})^2\cdot (\frac{1}{4}) + 3(\frac{3}{4})\cdot (\frac{1}{4})^2 + (\frac{1}{4})^3 = \frac{37}{64}$

I solved the system of three equations with three unknowns $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ using the augmented matrix.
$$\begin{bmatrix}
P_3&1&1&P_4\\
P_4&P_3&1&P_5\\
P_5&P_4&P_3&P_6\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$\alpha = \frac{1}{4}; \beta = \frac{3}{16}; \gamma = \frac{9}{64}$

A more sophisticated method probably arrives via $(\frac{1}{4}); (\frac{1}{4})(\frac{3}{4}); (\frac{1}{4})(\frac{3}{4})^2$